# How can I restrict users to delete other's posts in django using class based views?

Tags: python, django

my **views.py** file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    UserPassesTestMixin,
)
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/index.html"
    context_object_name = "posts"
    ordering = ["-date_posted"]

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'genere', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(UpdateView, LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    model = Post
    success_url = "blog-home"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

class PostDeleteView(DeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    model = Post
    success_url = "/"
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html')
```

My **models.py**:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genere = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} by {self.author}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

my **urls.py** url:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", PostListView.as_view(), name="blog-home"),
    path("about", views.about, name="blog-about"),
    path("post/<int:pk>", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="blog-detail"),
    path("post/new", PostCreateView.as_view(), name="blog-create"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/update", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="blog-update"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/delete", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="blog-delete"),

]
```

index.html

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row tm-row">
        {% for post in posts %}
            <article class="col-12 col-md-6 tm-post">
                <hr class="tm-hr-primary">
                <a href="{% url 'blog-detail' post.id %}" class="effect-lily tm-post-link tm-pt-60">
                    <div class="tm-post-link-inner">
                        <img src="{% static 'img/img-01.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <span class="position-absolute tm-new-badge">New</span>
                    <h2 class="tm-pt-30 tm-color-primary tm-post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                </a>
                <p class="tm-pt-30">
                    {{ post.content|safe|truncatewords:"30"|linebreaks }}
                </p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between tm-pt-45">
                    <span class="tm-color-primary">{{ post.genere }}</span>
                    <span class="tm-color-primary">{{ post.date_posted|date:'N j,Y' }}</span>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <span>36 comments</span>
                    <span>by {{ post.author }}</span>
                </div>
            </article>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
{% endblock %}
```

post_detail.html:

```html
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <article class="col-12 col-md-6 tm-post">
        <hr class="tm-hr-primary">
        <a href="" class="effect-lily tm-post-link tm-pt-60">
            <div class="tm-post-link-inner">
                <img src="{% static 'img/img-01.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <span class="position-absolute tm-new-badge">New</span>
            <h2 class="tm-pt-30 tm-color-primary tm-post-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
            {% if object.author == user %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="{% url 'blog-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'blog-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
            {% endif %}
        </a>
            <p class="tm-pt-30">
                {{ object.content }}
            </p>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between tm-pt-45">
            <span class="tm-color-primary">{{ object.genere }}</span>
            <span class="tm-color-primary">{{ object.date_posted|date:'N j,Y' }}</span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>36 comments</span>
            <span>by {{ object.author }}</span>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

post_confirm_delete.html:

```html
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>Are You Sure You Want To Delete "{{ object.title }}"</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Yes, I'm Sure</button>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'blog-detail' object.id %}">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, what I'm getting is that suppose 2 person **jeff** and **ram** are users so ram cannot update the posts of jeff and vice versa.
And if jeff views the post of ram, so he does not get the **update** and **delete**, so he cannot edit the post of ram but if jeff goes to "127.0.0.1:8000/post/9/delete" from "127.0.0.1:800/post/9",
So he get the confirm delete page and he can even delete his post.

How can I fix this bug in my project??????

Answer (score 0):

you can use get_queryset() to restrict query in database

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView, LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    model = Post
    success_url = "blog-home"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

     def get_queryset(self):
            pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
            return self.model.objects.filter(pk=pk,user=self.request.user)
```